# Update Cookies in Session Using python-requests Module

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, session-cookies, python-requests, http-request

I'm using *python-requests* module to handle oAuth request and response.
I want to set received *access_token* (response content as *dict*) in `requests.session.cookies` object.

How can I update existing cookies of session with received response from server?

**[EDIT]**

```
self.session = requests.session(auth=self.auth_params)
resp = self.session.post(url, data=data, headers=self.headers)
content = resp.content
```

I want to do something like:

```
requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(self.session.cookies).update(content)
```

Here, `requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(self.session.cookies)` returns *dict* with one session key. Now, I want to update received response content in `self.session.cookies`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me. hope it can help to someone else.

I want to update session.cookies variable with received response values from post request.
so, same request value can be used in another post/get request.

here, what I did:

1) updated requests module to 1.0.3 version.

2) created 2 functions

```
   session = requests.session() 
   def set_SC(cookie_val):
            for k,v in cookie_dict.iteritems():
                if not isinstance(v, str):
                    cookie_dict[k] =  str(v) 
            requests.utils.add_dict_to_cookiejar(session.cookies,
                                                 cookie_val)

    def get_SC():
            return requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(session.cookies)

    In another function:
    setSC(response.content)
```

Comment: This sound like a workaround, i.e. why do request doesn't save cookies of a post call ? see https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt in section 5.1 example. I'll raise it to requests

Answer (score 4):

`requests` can do that for you, provided you tell it all the `requests` you make are part of the same `session`:

```
>>> import requests
>>> s = requests.session()
>>> s.get('https://www.google.com')
<Response [200]>
>>> s.cookies
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[Cookie(version=0, name='NID'...
```

Subsequent requests made using `s.get` or `s.post` **will re-use and update the cookies** the server sent back to the client.

---

To add a Cookie on your own to a **single request**, you would simply add it via the cookies parameter.

```
>>> s.get('https://www.google.com', cookies = {'cookieKey':'cookieValue'})
```

Unless the server sends back a new value for the provided cookie, the session will **not retain** the provided cookie.

Comment: thanks, how it will work for post request. can you give example ?

Comment: I'm getting {'access_token':'Somecode'} in response, I want to set the same dict in existing session object's cookies. after getting response. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: @Yajushi You don't need to, so long as you use a `session` object, `requests` will re-use the cookies in subsequent requests automatically. For the `post` request, do: `s.post(url, data = {k:v})`

Comment: but, I want to set response content (from post request) in session.cookies.Please check edit.
Please, correct me if I misunderstood.

Comment: Thank You for quick reply. for me, it wasn't updating cookies automatically specially for post request. please check my answer, it worked for me.

Comment: Subsequent requests do not seem to reuse the same cookies.

Comment: Incorrect information. Passed parameters are not persistent. And this doesn't solve the issue over updating cookies.

Answer (score 2):

In order to provide a cookie yourself to the `requests` module you can use the cookies parameter **for a single request** and give it a cookie jar or dict like object containing the cookie(s).

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('https://www.example.com', cookies {'cookieKey':'cookieValue'})
```

But **if you want to retain the provided cookie** without having to set the cookies parameter everytime, you can use a reqests session which you can also pass to other funtions so they can use and update the same cookies:

```
>>> session = requests.session()
>>> session.cookies.set('cookieKey', 'cookieName')
# In order to avoid cookie collisions
# and to only send cookies to the domain / path they belong to
# you have to provide these detail via additional parameters
>>> session.cookies.set('cookieKey', 'cookieName', path='/', domain='www.example.com')
```