# Trying to load cookie into requests session from dictionary

Tags: python, session, cookies, python-requests

I'm working with the python requests library. I am trying to load a requests session with a cookie from a dictionary:

```
cookie = {'name':'my_cookie','value': 'kdfhgfkj' ,'domain':'.ZZZ.org', 'expires':'Fri, 01-Jan-2020 00:00:00 GMT'}
```

I've tried:

```
s.cookies.set_cookie(cookie)
```

but this gives:

```
File "....lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 298, in set_cookie
    if hasattr(cookie.value, 'startswith') and cookie.value.startswith('"') and cookie.value.endswith('"'):
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'value'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12):

`cookies` has a dictionary-like interface, you can use `update()`:

```
s.cookies.update(cookie)
```

Or, just add `cookies` to the next request:

```
session.get(url, cookies=cookie)
```

It would "merge" the request cookies with session cookies and the newly added cookies would be retained for subsequent requests, see also:

- [Update Cookies in Session Using python-requests Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971649/update-cookies-in-session-using-python-requests-module)

Answer (score 0):

[session.cookies.set_cookie](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar.set_cookie)'s parameter should be [Cookie object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#cookie-objects), NOT **dict** (of cookie)

if you want add new cookie into `session.cookies` from dict, you can use:

- [session.cookies.set](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar.set)

or

- [requests.cookies.create_cookie](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/requests/cookies/) + [session.cookies.set_cookie](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar.set_cookie)

more detail pls refer to [my another post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224054/how-to-add-a-cookie-to-the-cookiejar-in-python-requests-library/74652745#74652745)