# How to make a "RequestsCookieJar" object for a GET request from an existing cookie as "dictionary" type in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, web, cookies, python-requests

I've extracted some cookies in my python code in the form of a list of Dictionaries and each dictionary is a cookie like example below:

```
[
    {
        "domain": "x.com",
        "httpOnly": True,
        "name": "Username_COOKIE",
        "path": "/",
        "sameSite": "Lax",
        "secure": False,
        "value": "some value",
    },
    {
        "domain": "x.com",
        "expiry": 1676724072,
        "httpOnly": False,
        "name": "ASP.NET_SessionId",
        "path": "/",
        "sameSite": "Lax",
        "secure": False,
        "value": "some value",
    },
    {
        "domain": "x.com",
        "expiry": 1676810425,
        "httpOnly": False,
        "name": "_gid",
        "path": "/",
        "sameSite": "Lax",
        "secure": False,
        "value": "some value",
    }
```

Now I want to send a new GET request using these cookies. The `request.get()` method gets cookies in it's parameter as "RequestsCookieJar" object. My question is how can I make a "RequestsCookieJar" object using my dictionaries to pass it to the `request.get()` method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to load cookie into requests session from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928942/trying-to-load-cookie-into-requests-session-from-dictionary)

Comment: @dskrypa No my cookies are in the form of a list of dictionaries and I want to make a "RequestsCookieJar" object.

Answer (score 0):

If you first alter the structure a bit with

```py
cookieList = [  {'domain': 'x.com', 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'Username_COOKIE', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'Lax', 'secure': False, 'value': 'some value'},
                {'domain': 'x.com', 'expiry': 1676724072, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'ASP.NET_SessionId', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'Lax', 'secure': False, 'value': 'some value'},
                {'domain': 'x.com', 'expiry': 1676810425, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '_gid', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'Lax', 'secure': False, 'value': 'some value'}  ]

for ci, c in enumerate(cookieList):
    if 'httpOnly' in c: 
        cookieList[ci]['rest'] = {'HttpOnly': c['httpOnly']}
        del cookieList[ci]['httpOnly']
    if 'expiry' in c:
        cookieList[ci]['expires'] = c['expiry']
        del cookieList[ci]['expiry']
```

so that `cookieList` looks like

> ```py
> [{'domain': 'x.com',
>   'name': 'Username_COOKIE',
>   'path': '/',
>   'sameSite': 'Lax',
>   'secure': False,
>   'value': 'some value',
>   'rest': {'HttpOnly': True}},
>  {'domain': 'x.com',
>   'name': 'ASP.NET_SessionId',
>   'path': '/',
>   'sameSite': 'Lax',
>   'secure': False,
>   'value': 'some value',
>   'rest': {'HttpOnly': False},
>   'expires': 1676724072},
>  {'domain': 'x.com',
>   'name': '_gid',
>   'path': '/',
>   'sameSite': 'Lax',
>   'secure': False,
>   'value': 'some value',
>   'rest': {'HttpOnly': False},
>   'expires': 1676810425}]
> ```

then you can turn it into a [RequestsCookieJar](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar) object with

```py
# import requests
cKeys = ['version', 'name', 'value', 'port', 'domain', 'path', 'secure', 
         'expires', 'discard', 'comment', 'comment_url', 'rest', 'rfc2109']

jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()
for c in cookieList: jar.set(**{k:v for k,v in c.items() if k in cKeys})
```

You can now [use](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies) `jar` like **<kbd>requests.get(url, cookies=jar)</kbd>**, or view it with `print(repr(jar))` which should output something like

> ```py
> <RequestsCookieJar[
>   Cookie(version=0, name='ASP.NET_SessionId', value='some value', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='x.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1676724072, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': False}, rfc2109=False), 
>   Cookie(version=0, name='Username_COOKIE', value='some value', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='x.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': True}, rfc2109=False), 
>   Cookie(version=0, name='_gid', value='some value', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='x.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1676810425, discard=True, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': False}, rfc2109=False)
> ]>
> ```

---

You *might* also be able to just get away with

```py
cookieList = [  {'domain': 'x.com', 'httpOnly': True, 'name': 'Username_COOKIE', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'Lax', 'secure': False, 'value': 'some value'},
                {'domain': 'x.com', 'expiry': 1676724072, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'ASP.NET_SessionId', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'Lax', 'secure': False, 'value': 'some value'},
                {'domain': 'x.com', 'expiry': 1676810425, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '_gid', 'path': '/', 'sameSite': 'Lax', 'secure': False, 'value': 'some value'}  ]

cookiesDict = {c['name']:c['value'] for c in cookieList if 'name' in c and 'value' in c}
resp = requests.get(url, cookies=cookiesDict)
```